# Group action on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ circle

Tags: group-theory, geometry, group-actions

Consider the natural group action of $O(2)$ on the set of pairs of vectors of the $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ unit circle.

What is it's orbit for the group $O(2)$, give a total invariant.?

Same questions of $SO(2)$, and give the quotient $X/SO(2)$ (probably the space of all classes of orbits)

Thanks for any advice.

It seems as though $O(2)$ yields all possible pairs of vectors of $\mathbb{S}^1$ $\ldots$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "total invariant"?  Cheers!

Comment: A single orbit cannot contain all pairs of vectors. After all $O(2)$ preserves the angle between the two vectors. Seconding Robert Lewis' query.

Comment: Yes I meant if you apply all possible rotations on one vector you will get the whole circle. So if you do the same thing on a pair of vectors you will get two spaced out parametric circles...  That would be linked to SO(2) but wirh O(2) we need to add the reflections,  How could I express such an orbit ?   I am not sure either what the exercise means by invariant, perhaps a stabilizer?

Comment: The comment of @JyrkiLahtonen gives the answer to this question: angle is the requested total invariant, which simply means an invariant having the property that this vector pair and that vector pair are in the same orbit if and only if they have the same total invariant (in this case, the same angle).

Comment: Ok thanks. So two pairs of vectors are in the same orbit if and only if they have the same angle. How do we compare both groups for this action?

Comment: The difference between action by $O(2)$ as opposed to $SO(2)$ is that the latter preserves "clockwise/ccw". So if vector $u$ is gotten from the vector $v$ by rotating it counterclockwise by an angle $\theta$, then usually there is no element of $SO(2)$ that swaps $u$ and $v$, but there always is such an element in $O(2)$ (orthogonal reflection about the bisector). Of course, $\theta=\pi=180^\circ$ is an exceptional case here.

Comment: Yes O(2) sends orthonormal basis to orthonormal basis whereas SO(2) preserves oriented orthonormal basis. I found it a bit tricky to translate into the language of group theory ^^    This action looks close to how we define oriented angles in affine geometry, by using a representative of the class

Comment: If all is crystal clear to you now, you are welcome to self-answer. That way possible lingering unclear steps come to surface, and you can check the question as *answered*.